# PyQt4 : Connect splitter

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to connect splitters to make a "cross" splitters between 4 widgets. I tried to do it using signal and slot between two splitters, and even if no errors occured, the behavior is not the one I hope (in fact nothing happens).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.initUI()

        self.window.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)
        self.showMaximized()

    def initUI(self) :
        self.window = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.editor1 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editor2 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editor3 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editor4 = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        self.split1 = QtGui.QSplitter()
        self.split2 = QtGui.QSplitter()
        self.split3 = QtGui.QSplitter()
        self.split2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.split3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.split2.addWidget(self.editor1)
        self.split2.addWidget(self.editor2)
        self.split3.addWidget(self.editor3)
        self.split3.addWidget(self.editor4)

        self.connect(self.split2, QtCore.SIGNAL("splitterMoved"), self.split3.moveSplitter)
        self.connect(self.split3, QtCore.SIGNAL("splitterMoved"), self.split2.moveSplitter)

        self.split1.addWidget(self.split2)
        self.split1.addWidget(self.split3)

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.split1)
        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)

def main() :
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qApp.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    aw = ApplicationWindow()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Doesn't ``self.split3.moveSplitter`` need arguments  (``QSplitter.moveSplitter (self, int pos, int index)`` from http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplitter.html#moveSplitter ) ? You are not telling it where to move, right?

Comment: And how can I tell him where to move ? I'm lost here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I found how to do that using python :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle("Cluster View")
        self.initUI()

        self.window.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)
        self.showMaximized()

    def splitterMoved(self, sender) :
        print ("ok", sender)
        receiver = self.split2 if sender is self.split3 else self.split3
        receiver.blockSignals(True)
        receiver.setSizes(sender.sizes())
        receiver.blockSignals(False)

    def initUI(self) :
        self.window = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.editor1 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editor2 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editor3 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editor4 = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        self.split1 = QtGui.QSplitter()
        self.split2 = QtGui.QSplitter()
        self.split3 = QtGui.QSplitter()
        self.split2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.split3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.split2.addWidget(self.editor1)
        self.split2.addWidget(self.editor2)
        self.split3.addWidget(self.editor3)
        self.split3.addWidget(self.editor4)

        self.connect(self.split2, QtCore.SIGNAL("splitterMoved(int, int)"), lambda x : self.splitterMoved(self.split2))
        self.connect(self.split3, QtCore.SIGNAL("splitterMoved(int, int)"), lambda x : self.splitterMoved(self.split3))

        self.split1.addWidget(self.split2)
        self.split1.addWidget(self.split3)

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.split1)
        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)

def main() :
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qApp.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    aw = ApplicationWindow()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Maybe there are better way to do that, but at least it works now.

Comment: That looks pretty solid and does pretty much what I mentioned earlier by sending the two ``int`` with the signal. Well done ;).